# Condition for closed orbits

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

> I'm working on a central force problem in which the potential is 
>   $$ U(r)=-\frac{\alpha}{r}\left( 1+ \frac{\beta}{r} \right) $$
>   I'm asked what condition has to be satisfied for the orbit to be closed.

I'm aware that [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) suggests that the form of the potential allows closed orbits and in other books like Marion's they have a condition that goes like:
$$ \Delta{\phi}=2\int_{ r_{min}}^{r_{max}}\frac{\frac{L}{r^{2}}\text{d}r}{\sqrt{2\mu \left[E-\frac{L^{2}}{2\mu r^{2}}+\frac{\alpha}{r}\left(1+\frac{\beta}{r}\right) \right]}}=2\pi\frac{a}{b} $$
with $a$ and $b$ being natural numbers.

I already have the condition I'm asked (**It's not a homework**). But I don't understand where that $\frac{a}{b}$ having to be rational comes from. Is that a geometrical reasoning? It has to do with Bertrand's theorem? It looks somewhat like Lissajous curves and it may be something simple that I don't know.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Is the issue the interpretation of the ratio $a/b$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The orbit is in 2d and "oscillates" between a minimum and a maximum $r$. The position in the plane if given by $(r(t),\phi(t))$ but here $t$ has been eliminated and you have $r(\phi)$.

As you go once from $r_{min}$ to $r_{max}(\phi)$, the body will advance along the orbit by an angular distance $\Delta \phi$.  As you go from $r_{min}$ to $r_{max}$ and back to $r_{min}$, you advance by an angle $2\Delta \phi$.

To get a closed orbit, you must eventually come back to your starting point, meaning you must make an integer number $b$ of trips between $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ while advancing by an integer multiple $a$ of $2\pi$.  This is the geometrical origin of the $2\pi a/b$ factor.

---

Edit: In answer to a comment, two situations are illustrated below.  In both cases $r_{min}=1$ and $r_{max}=3$, and these values are shows as red thick lines.  These values restrict the orbits to a ring of inner radius $1$ and outer radius $3$.  The radius oscillates between $1$ and $3$ with some frequency $\omega_r$, as can be seen by the black lines in the figures.

[image] 
[image]

The parametric equations for the figures on the left and the right are, respectively,
$$
r(\phi)=2+\cos\left(\sqrt{3}\phi\right)\, ,\qquad 
\hbox{and}\qquad r(\phi)=2+\cos\left(\phi\right)
$$
In the first case, the ratio $\omega_\phi/\omega_r$ is not commensurate since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, and the orbit does not close.  The best way to see this is to note that the start of the parametric curve is at $r=3,\phi=0$ but, at the end of the curve, $r\ne 3$.  Because the ratio $\omega_\phi/\omega_r$ is irrational, the orbit would eventually densely fill the ring.

In the second case, on the other hand, the ratio $\omega_\phi/\omega_r$ is commensurate, and one can show (if we follow the curve through its $\phi$ evolution) that in fact it goes from $r_{min}\to r_{max}\to r_{min}$ exactly once when $\phi$ goes from $0\to 2\pi$.

Comment: @DavidLeonardoRamos, there is a simpler requirement for a closed orbit.  Based on the way that gravitational potential energy is defined, a closed orbit occurs when $U(r)<0$.

Comment: How's that? You mean always being negative? I don't see it clear.

Comment: @DavidWhite I think you may be misunderstanding the question: closed as in closing on itself in 2d.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, can you elaborate?

Comment: I think he means that is not sufficient that the orbit is bounded by $r_{min}, r_{max}$

Comment: @DavidWhite Edited my answer following your comment.  Hopefully this is enough.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, thanks.  The title of the posting was so brief that I obviously mis-interpreted what the OP was asking.

Comment: @DavidWhite Right.  What put me on the right track was the expression for $\Delta \phi$.  Anyways I think your comment made me improve my answer (I would hope).